# Angular throws error "Couldn't follow symbolic link"

Tags: angular, macos, typescript, gradle, npm

I am not able to build angular (angular 6).This happened after I upgraded node modules. I get this error:

> Failed to capture fingerprint of output files for task
>   ':pbr-angular-common:setupAngular' property '$1' during up-to-date
>   check.
>
> > Could not list contents of '/Users/xxx/git/xxx/angular-common/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp'.
> >     Couldn't follow symbolic link.

**This are the things I tried**:

1. Removed folders from .bin
2. Removed .bin folder
3. Removed node_modules compeltely and reinstalled as mentioned in this link
   [[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x][1])
4. Removed symbolic links as mentioned in this link:
   [https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/issues/202][2]
5. Cleared npm cache (npm clean cache)
6. Cleared .gradle (includes gradle nodejs cache)
7. Did gradlew clean build re deploy
8. Did brew uninstall node, brew install node, brew unlink node && link node

Here are the `nodejs` and `npm versions` I use

```
npm --version
6.11.3
node --version
v12.11.1
```

I am working on MacOS mojave version 10.14.5. Please
Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you removed `node_modules` correctly & ran `npm install` again? That should fix the issue. Command: `rm -rf node_modules && npm i`

Comment: Tried that too..did not work!

Comment: This is an issue with node version 12. Downgrading to node version 10.16.3 helped me to get a successful build.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while building the application and
"rm -rf node_modules && npm i" didn't worked for me.

this error was because of node version 12

following commands solved the issue for me

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 10.9.0
```

so basically i just downgraded my node version